# OData with Visual Studio 2005 and .NET 2.0

Tags: visual-studio, odata

Is it possible to use OData with Visual Studio 2005 and .NET framework 2.0 ?

Comment: Do you want to consume an OData service or provide one?  Consuming one from .Net 2.0 is easy.

Comment: I was looking into providing OData service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer: Since OData is an open protocol, not a piece of software, technically you can use .NET Framework 2.0 to implement it.  However, to use the pre-supplied libraries from Microsoft, you will need .NET 3.5 SP1 and above.

Answer (score 1):

It's sad that you can find implementations for PHP, Java, Objective C... and for the .net framework only available for 3.5 or above,there is still a lot of legacy app's that are still sticked to the 2.0 version of the framework, in some cases this can be a showstopper.